# clone imagick object - wrong output

Tags: php, imagemagick, clone, imagick

Following code produces entirely different image clone. Let me show you:
[image]

[image]

```
$image = 'image_input.jpg';
$im = new Imagick();

$im->pingimage($image);
$im->readimage($image);

$im_clone = clone $im;

$im_clone->writeimage('image_output.jpg');
$im_clone->clear();
$im->clear();
```

Comment: What version of imagemagick and php are you using?

Comment: Also, have you tried referencing the full path to the input image?

Comment: It produces the same output while using full path too.

PHP Version: 5.5.22
Imagick: 3.4.0RC6 
ImageMagick: 6.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with PHP 5.6:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readimage('input.jpg');

$im_clone = clone $image;
$im_clone->writeimage('result.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: Just tried without $image->pingimage('nput.jpg') and it **works well** on PHP 5.5. Apparently it is **Imagick::pingimage()** method which screw somehow the results. The question remain why.

Comment: Why do you want to call that anyway? It only reads just enough of the image to determine its size.

Comment: Now after I looked in docs I see it is quite useless in a context that I've used it. I did so, becouse I read somewhere about its advantages, but I saw there also some depracted behaviours. It must have been an outdated source. I will check this conversation as the answer - maybe it will open someone's eyes just like it did for me.